# Magento 2: Convert Magento\Framework\Phrase into string

Tags: magento2, translate

How can i convert this variable into string:

```
$var = __("Welcome");
```

because when i put in `strpos` function it will return an error:

```
strpos($var, 'om');
```

> Uncaught TypeError: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given strpos(Object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)

Answer (score 6):

This should work.

```
$var = __("Welcome")->render();
```